# direct input with svg code to html some problems and some questions

Tags: css, svg

so im fooling around with svg on codepen.io and i have a few questions

1. why does the height and width attributes have no effect in the html (found in the image element of the svg)? i have read that removing these attributes and using css to size is best practice, what do you think?
2. does using the object tag to link to an svg file allow for the same customizability that inline svg would with regards to css and js? if yes, does this benifit outweigh having an extra http request for the linked image?
3. when the need for icons arise is it better to use font icons or svg icons?(font icons are new to me, do they allow editing with css and js? are they easy to make? are they smaller in file size?)
4. in this specific pen https://codepen.io/cole-pratt/pen/xxGdmRN there are two icons. the first icon has a blue gradient, the second icon is suppose to have a green gradient but for some reason it has adopted the blue gradient even though the colors for these are specified within each element (as far as i know) presuming that inline is better than the object tag and also presuming svg is more suitable than font icons how can this colour situation be remedied in the most efficient way?
5. regarding the previous pen... i attempted to use svg:hover to change the fill colour. this did not work even though the height property was applied. anyone got a reason for this?
6. any other things i should know abouot svg and html please fire away

the following is the css from the pen. its pretty irrelevant but this website wont allow me to post without some code

```
body {
  background-color: rgb(240,240,240);
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}

nav {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row-reverse norap;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0px 15px 10px -15px grey;
}

svg {
  height: 75px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

svg:hover {
  fill: white;
}
```

if you have read this far, much apreciated. looking forward to your replies

Comment: try `svg:hover path {
  fill: white;
}` Also you have a repeated `id`

Comment: It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks!